# How to use chimpmail in Meteor + React?

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, mailchimp

First of all thanks for taking the time to read this, I have to say I'm new in the world of web development. I've been asking to implement mailchimp (I never heard of it) in to a project, for this I just started to search info about the [chimpmail API](https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/lists/subscribe.php) also I followed the tutorial from  [meteorchef](https://themeteorchef.com/recipes/mailing-lists-with-mailchimp/) and the problem is I can make this work, I found quite difficult to implement this with React. I have problems with my methods when I input a mail and run the onSubmit method, the console output says "method handleSubscriber not found". So far I just made the handleSubscriber part from the tutorial, I'm not displaying any email list jet. I'm running my Meteor app with `meteor --settings=settings.json`. I will really appreciate some help.

**Update**

I received a useful comment that point it out that I should add my methods file to my server directory. By doing this I no longer got the  "method handleSubscriber not found" instead of that I got now `Exception while invoking method 'handleSubscriber' Error: Match error: Expected object, got null`

This are my Meteor packages:

```
meteor-base
mobile-experience
mongo
blaze-html-templates
reactive-var
jquery
tracker
library

standard-minifier-css
standard-minifier-js    
es5-shim
ecmascript

react-meteor-data@0.2.6-beta.16
accounts-ui
accounts-password
practicalmeteor:mocha
miro:mailchimp
fortawesome:fontawesome
themeteorchef:bert
standard-app-packages
underscore
themeteorchef:jquery-validation
check
```

This is my settings.json

```
{
  "public": {},
  "private": {
     "MailChimp": {
       "apiKey": "theapikey",
       "listId": "thislsitId"
      }
   }
}
```

The chimpMail.js

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { check } from 'meteor/check';

const settings = Meteor.settings.private.MailChimp;
const chimp = new MailChimp( settings.apiKey, { version: '2.0' });
const listId = settings.listId;

Meteor.methods({
  'handleSubscriber'(subscriber) {
    check(subscriber, {
      email: String,
      action: String,
    });
  try {
    const subscribe = chimp.call('lists', subscriber.action, {
      id: listId,
       email: {
        email: subscriber.email,
       },
    });
     return subscribe;
    } catch (exception) {
      return exception;
   }
 },
});
```

This is my emailSubscription.jsx

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';

class EmailSubscription extends Component {
   handleOnSubmit(event) {
     event.preventDefault();

     Meteor.call('handleSubscriber', this.props.subscriber,        
       function(error, response) {
       if (error) {
          Bert.alert(error.reason, "warning");
       } else {
       if (response.complete || response.euid) {
          const subscribeMessage = 'Please confirm your email to  
           complete your subscription!';
          const unsubscribeMessage = subscriber.email + 'successfully 
           unsubscribed!';
          const message = subscriber.action === "subscribe" ? 
           subscribeMessage : unsubscribeMessage;

          Bert.alert(message, "success");
       } else {
         Bert.alert(response.message, "warning");
       }
     }
   });
}

render() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <form onSubmit={this.handleOnSubmit.bind(this)} 
         className="emal-submit"
       >
        <input type="email" placeholder="email@example.com" />
        <button>Sign Me Up!</button>
      </form>
    </div>
   );
  }
}
export default createContainer(() => {
}, EmailSubscription);
```

Comment: "method handlerSubscriber not found" is say that your method. Please import the methods file in the server directory.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I forgot that! I imported the mailChimp.js to my server directory and I got the following error: ` Exception while invoking method 'handleSubscriber' Error: Match error: Expected object, got null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "method handlerSubscriber not found" is say that your method.

Please import the methods file in the server directory.

> Exception while invoking method 'handleSubscriber' Error: Match error: Expected object, got null

This is the exception you are getting because subscriber needs to be an object but you are sending null from the client. check function throwing this exception.

Comment: Thank you, I just solved the problem and now it works! I'll update the post with the answer!!!